# How can I pass a Django template context variable to JS function

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I am trying to create a simple web link toggle for following or unfollowing a question in my app. I got close using the info [My Own Like Button: Django + Ajax -- How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007453/my-own-like-button-django-ajax-how) but am not quite there.

My problem is that I cannot dynamically pass question.id to my JS function as the answer in the above link implies. Ie

The hard-wired JS code below DOES work. It passes `'12'` as a valid param for the view tied to `/question/follow-unfollow-inline/`. But when I try to replace `'12'` with a context variable `'{{ question.id }}'` from the template that calls this JS code, my function passes the string `'{{ question.id }}'` back to `/question/follow-unfollow-inline/` rather than it's value. How do I fix this?

```
$(function () {
    $("#follow_unfollow_toggle").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/question/follow-unfollow-inline/",
            data: { 'qid': '12' },
            success: function (e) {
                alert('Success!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

For now, I'm using `@csrf_exempt` on my view, but I know I should pass it as data.

Comment: Did you try having Django serve the JavaScript?

Comment: Hi. Not sure if this answers your question but when in Debug mode, all my static files are served by Django. Otherwise Amazon S3.

Comment: Stop serving it as a static file.

Comment: So insert the js directly into my template vs. calling from an external js file?

Comment: I tried that. It works if you only have one question to follow/unfollow, but I have a list of them. If I place my JS inside my loop, it works for the first question in the list only. If I place the JS outside the loop, I lose the content of the current question id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define it on your anchor tag with `data-` attribute:

Template:

```
<a id="follow_unfollow_toggle" href="#" data-qid="{{ question.id }}">Like</a>
```

Js file:

```
$(function () {
    $("#follow_unfollow_toggle").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/question/follow-unfollow-inline/",
            data: { 'qid': $(this).data('qid') },
            success: function (e) {
                alert('Success!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @dolan that worked great. I also realized I needed to change `id="follow_unfollow_toggle"` to `class="follow_unfollow_toggle"` so that my JS function fires for any question in my list of questions, not just the first.