# Django creating a custom like button for each item

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm trying to create my own like button but I am encountering some issues.

The code use Ajax with Django and I am getting an error message but I don't know what is wrong.

here is the code, mostly inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007453/my-own-like-button-django-ajax-how).

**article\models.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default='1')
    titre = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    [... some unrelated models ...]
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="likes")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titre

    @property
    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

**article\urls.py**

```
url(r'^like/$', views.like_button, name='like_button'),
```

**article\views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='/user')
def like_button(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.user
        id = request.POST.get('pk', None)
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=id)

        if article.likes.filter(id=user.id).exists():
            article.likes.remove(user)
        else:
            article.likes.add(user)

    context = {'likes_count': article.total_likes}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context), content_type='application/json')
```

(As you can see I am trying to get the article id and not the slug)

**article.html**

```
<div>
    {% for a in article %}
    [... some unrelated html ...]

    <input type="button" class="like" name="{{ a.id }}" value="Like" />
    <p>count : {{ a.total_likes }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<script>
$('.like').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "{% url 'like_button' %}",
               data: {'pk': $(this).attr('name'), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
               dataType: "json",
               success: function(response) {
                      alert('Company likes count is now ' + response.count_likes);
                },
               error: function(rs, e) {
                      alert(rs.responseText); #No Article matches the given query.
               }
          });
    })
</script>
```

the error say that No Article matches the given query.

What should I change in order to make this work?

Comment: `raised an error` is not giving us any info to let us help you. The picture is not that useful either. You need to edit your question to tell us what error do you have.

Comment: You are using a click event on and `id`, but you have more than one button so `id` wouldn't work. You need to use `class`: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

Comment: @ShangWang made some changes to the question, it says that No Article matches the given query.

Comment: That means the `pk` you passed in doesn't match any record in database. You might do `print id` in your views.py to see what `id` did you get.

Comment: @ShangWang NameError : name 'id' is not defined. Then how can I get the article ID ?

Comment: You have to add the print statement after you do `id = request.POST.get('pk', None)`. Otherwise how can python know which `id` to print?

Comment: @ShangWang I am having a hard to trying to print the id when I add it after `id = request.POST.get('pk', None)` nothing is shown in the console, even when I click the buttons, is it possible to show it in ajax using an alert ?

Comment: Well then most likely your `pk` is None.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101430/discussion-between-sia-and-shang-wang).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I can see that "id="like" is used in a for loop so it make multiple buttons with same ID. ID must be unique

Tryto change id with class like

```
<div>
    {% for a in article %}
    [... some unrelated html ...]

    <input type="button" class="like" name="{{ a.id }}" value="Like" />
    <p>count : {{ a.total_likes }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<script>
$('.like').click(function(){
  var pk = $(this).attr('name');
  $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "{% url 'like_button' %}",
           data: {'pk': pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
           dataType: "json",
           success: function(response) {
                  alert('Company likes count is now ' + response.count_likes);
            },
           error: function(rs, e) {
                  alert('Something went wrong.'); #getting this message.
           }
      });
    })
</script>
```