# How to implement a Like button django

Tags: django

Please I am a newbie in programming,dont be pissed if my question is too rudimentary or annoying.I have a model that goes like this

```
class Feed(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='feeds')
    text=models.TextField(blank=False,max_length=500)
    user_like=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name="likes",blank=True)
```

I want to create a stand-alone Like button for this model to add `user` to `user_like` when click by a user in template.I have a view like this

```
def like_feed(request,pk):
    feed=get_object_or_404(Feed,pk=pk)
    user=request.user
    if request.method=='POST'
        if feed.user_like.filter(id=user.id).exists():
            feed.user_like.remove(user)  
            #make the change and reload the page 
            return render(request , 'index.html' ,{'feed':feed,})
        else:
            feed.user_like.add(user)   
            #make the change and reload the page
            return render(request , 'index.html' ,{'feed':feed,})
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^likes/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.like_feed,name='like_feed_url')
```

and somewhere in the template I have

```
<form action="{% url 'like_feed' pk=feed.pk %}" method="post">
<input type="button" id="like" name="like_button" value="Like" /></form>
```

As I said I am not really sure what I am doing,I am just experimenting.Kindly help me out.

Comment: And what's wrong with the code you have now? What happens when you try it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman. It doesnt bring any error but on clicking the button,it doesnt perform any action.

Comment: @Bolaji How about you let an Ajax call do the backend like/dislike for you, instead of having to refresh the entire page per each like/dislike? try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007453/my-own-like-button-django-ajax-how

Comment: Thanks @Rexford I dont know AJAX but I've copied and pasted the solution that was given in the link.Django doesnt show any error but on clicking the button,it doesnt perform any action.

Comment: Check `https://github.com/malisit/django-likeit` out!